# tt-news category tree broken after 3.0.1 update?

Tags: typo3

How can I fix a broken category tree after a 3.0.1 update from a 2.5 tt-news extension? In the category dialog I can only select some of my huge category tree.

Comment: Could you provide further details? Maybe a screenshot would be helpful. Did you take a look inside the DB to see if you can figure out what and why it's broken?

Comment: Problem is solved. Thank you.

Comment: It would help others if you answer your own question here and explain how you were able to solve it!

Comment: @lumbric: Fixed it, can you give an upvote, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tree was broken or incomplete because after the update the flexform has changed and thus the selected parent category couldn't be retrieved properly to display the incomplete or partial vertex of the tree. But the update came with an installer to address this problem. I read the internet about it and I've found the tt-news installer in the EM when I click on the extension. Thanks to tt-news!